# CreateThread crash

Tags: c++, c, winapi

```
DWORD WINAPI getOffset(uintptr_t BaseAddy, uintptr_t endAddy, byte aob[], int bytessize, LPVOID returnValue)
{
    MessageBox(NULL, "321", "123", MB_OK);
    return 0;
}
```

Вызываю:

```
CreateThread(NULL, NULL, reinterpret_cast<LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE>(getOffset(BaseAddy + 0xd7d000, endAddy, presentAOB, 11, &presentOffset)), NULL, NULL, NULL);
```

Происходит краш программы сразу после MessageBox (на самом return 0). В чем может быть проблема и как ее исправить?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ваша функция `getOffset` возвращает 0, который вы переинтерпретируете в null-указатель и передаете в качестве указателя на функцию потока. Разумеется, все падает.

Функция потока не может быть null-указателем.

---

Если ваша задача состоит в том, чтобы вызвать вашу функцию из потока с вышеприведенными параметрами, то делать вам это придется следующим образом

1. Написать функцию потока, из которой будет делаться вызов `getOffset`

   ```
   DWORD myThreadFunction(LPVOID p)
   {
     ...
     getOffset(...);
     return 0;
   }
   ```
2. Подготовить структуру для передачи ваших параметров в поток, заполнить ее и передать указатель на нее в `CreateThread` вместе с указателем на функцию потока

   ```
   struct MyThreadParams
   {
     uintptr_t BaseAddy, endAddy;
     byte *aob;
     int bytessize;
     LPVOID returnValue;
   };

   ...
   MyThreadParams params = 
     { BaseAddy + 0xd7d000, endAddy, presentAOB, 11, &presentOffset };

   CreateThread(NULL, 0, myThreadFunction, &params, 0, NULL);
   ```
3. В функции потока получить этот указатель на структуру и использовать ее поля как аргументы для вызова вашей функции `getOffset`

   ```
   DWORD myThreadFunction(LPVOID p)
   {
     MyThreadParams *params = (MyThreadParams *) params;
     getOffset(params->BaseAddy, params->endAddy, params->aob, params->bytessize, 
       params->returnValue);
     return 0;
   }
   ```

Comment: Я уже пробовал возвращать 1. То же самое. Что необходимо передавать чтобы выйти из потока? При обозначении void reinterpret_cast ругается что не может перевести

Comment: Не понимаю вопроса. Вы еще не запустили никакого потока. Откуда вы собрались выходить? В CreateThread должен передаваться указатель на функцию потока. Вы передаете туда какие-то левые значения: 0 или 1. Все, разумеется, сразу падает. Где ваша функция потока?

Comment: То есть если я получил запуск MessageBox, значит он выполняется в том же потоке? Это не новый поток?
    CreateThread(NULL, NULL, reinterpret_cast<LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE>(getOffset(BaseAddy + 0xd7d000, endAddy, presentAOB, 11, &presentOffset)), NULL, NULL, NULL);
так и вызываю

Comment: @user2173645 Нет конечно. Ваша функция вызывается еще до CreateThread, а ее результат передается в CreateThread. Функция потока обязана иметь один параметр LPVOID.